# How to compile Qt5 QOCI plugin on Linux with Oracle client 12?

Tags: oracle, qt, qt5, qoci

The [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html) should do the trick, not for me:

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- OCI_INCDIR=/usr/include/oracle/10.1.0.3/client OCI_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/oracle/10.1.0.3/client/lib
make sub-oci
```

What I have tried:

```
cd /opt/Qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- OCI_INCDIR=/opt/oracle/db/prod/12.2.0/rdbms/public OCI_LIBDIR=/opt/oracle/db/prod/12.2.0/lib
make sub-oci
```

They assume that we have installed the RPM packages of the Instant Client Package SDK and I'm not in this case. I don't know how the client was installed, but I have no installed packages names Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did:

```
cd /opt/Qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci
```

Edit the file oci.pro:

- Comment `#QMAKE_USE += oci`
- Add `INCLUDEPATH += /opt/oracle/db/prod/12.2.0/rdbms/public`
- Add `LIBS += -L/opt/oracle/db/prod/12.2.0/lib -lclntsh -lclntshcore`
- Save and exit editor

Back in bash:

```
qmake oci.pro
make
make install
```

Done!